# Undefined symbols with debug builds in Firebase/CrashReporting

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Since updating to Firebase Crash Reporting 3.8.0 via Cocoapods, I see the following error during builds for Debug mode. I am able to build in Release mode without error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogNoFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRSystemLogger_6532fb37dc095ffa73463b57baf5fca7.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogBasicFormatter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRSystemLogger_6532fb37dc095ffa73463b57baf5fca7.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRSystemLogger_6532fb37dc095ffa73463b57baf5fca7.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(uploader_089041b840f448492d858d7daf481e47.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This occurs when the XCode setting *Build Active Architecture Only* is set to *NO* in debug mode.

Several of the Firebase SDKs rely on pods built from source.  By default, CocoaPods sets the *Build Active Architecture Only* to *YES* for all Pods built from source when running in Debug.  This mismatch causes the missing symbols you mentioned.

There are two options to fix the issue:

1. Switch *Build Active Architecture Only* to *YES* in debug on your
   main project.
2. Set your pods' *Build Active Architecture Only* to *NO* while in debug (taken from this [post](http://samwize.com/2014/05/15/resolving-cocoapods-build-error-due-to-targets-building-for-only-active-architecture/)):

   ```
   post_install do |installer_representation|
     installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
       end
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: where should I add pods' Build Active Architecture Only to NO, in Podfile?